# How to process JSON post response

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I am receiving the following successful response :

```
{"123abc": {"lat": 101.45, "lon": 777.87},"uid345":{"lat":12.09,"lon":98.08}}
```

After posting this jquery ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    url: postUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    },
    complete: function () {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        lat: 101.45,
        lon: 777.87,
        uid: '123abc'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (dataString) {
        alert(dataString);
    },
    error: function (error) {}
});
```

alert(datastring); prints [object object] in a alert window.

How can I process the received response?

p.s: I just completed a udacity web development course and this is new to me.

Comment: access properties as `datastring.lat` Or `datastring.[0].lat`. You'll get the gist how to access other's

Comment: jQuery Mobile isn't involved in your question.

Comment: FYI, that's to be expected. `alert` converts the argument to a string and the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`.

Comment: thanks for the hints and help , I will refer to the above link and sort it out . This will be more than enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `console` to check your response, that way you can expand the object out and what fields are available:

```
console.log(dataString);
```

There are a number of options for processing depending on what you want to do. The most used is iterating over your objects keys and displaying the appropriate info via a `for in` or `$.each` loop.

To iterate the `lat` and `lon` of each object, something like below will work:

```
for (var key in dataString) {
    console.log(dataString[key].lat);
    console.log(dataString[key].lon);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have all the latitudes and longitudes in a seprate list like python . I want to store them and print them as marker on google map

Answer (score 1):

access properties as `datastring.lat` Or `datastring.[0].lat`. You'll get the gist how to          access other's

If the later is true,

Do loop on datastring till `datastring.length`